# Select by two conditions in has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I struggle with creating a performant select of the database.
Following case:

A booking has 2 attributes `departure` and `arrival`.
Both attributes are type `date`.
I want to select all Persons with bookings with `departure: 1.month.ago` and no Booking in the future.

**Relation:**

```rb
class Booking
   has_many :persons, class_name: 'Person', through: :stays
end

class Stay
  belongs_to :booking, class_name: 'Booking'
  belongs_to :person, class_name: 'Person'
end

class Person
   has_many :bookings, class_name: 'Booking', through: :stays
end
```

Because there are ~3.800.000 Persons in the database I can't work with a selection by a ruby logic after selection.

I've tried some requests, but I do not get any result, even there are some.

```rb
Person.joins(:bookings).where('bookings.departure < ? AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bookings WHERE arrival >= ?)', 1.month.ago, Time.zone.today).find_each(&:clear)
```

Is it possible to have such a Database request, or do I need to work with one case in active record and the others by a logic?

```rb
Person.joins(:bookings).where('bookings.departure < ?', 1.month.ago).find_each do |pers|
  pers.clear unless pers.bookings.where('arrival >= ?', Time.zone.today).exists?  
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are just missing a join and subsequent filtering condition here:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bookings WHERE arrival >= ?)
```

In order to ensure this filters based on a specific person you will need to change this to:

```
NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM bookings 
  INNER JOIN stays ON stays.booking_id = bookings.id 
  WHERE arrival >= ? AND stays.person_id = people.id)
```

We should be able to convert this query in the ActiveRecord/Arel as follows:

```
Person.joins(:bookings)
  .where(bookings: {departure: ...1.month.ago})
  .where.not(
      Stay.select(1)
        .joins(:bookings)
        .where(bookings: {arrival: Time.zone.today..})
        .where(Stay.arel_table[:person_id].eq(Person.arel_table[:id]))
        .arel.exists
  )
```

This should result in the following query

```
SELECT 
  people.*
FROM 
  people 
  INNER JOIN stays ON stays.person_id = people.id
  INNER JOIN bookings ON bookings.id = stays.booking_id
WHERE 
  bookings.departure < '2024-02-26' 
AND 
  NOT (
    EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM 
        stays
        INNER JOIN bookings ON bookings.id = stays.booking_id 
      WHERE 
        stays.person_id = people.id 
        AND bookings.arrival >= '03-26-2024'))
```

Alternately you could go with 2 separate IN clauses. The code is a little cleaner but it will likely have a performance impact.

```
Person
  .where(id: 
    Stays.joins(:bookings).select(:person_id).where(bookings: {departure: ...1.month.ago}))
  .where.not(id: 
    Stays.joins(:bookings).select(:person_id).where(bookings:{arrival: Time.zone.today..}))
```

SQL:

```
SELECT 
  people.*
FROM 
  people 
WHERE 
  people.id IN ( 
    SELECT 
      stays.person_id
    FROM 
        stays
        INNER JOIN bookings ON bookings.id = stays.booking_id 
      WHERE 
        bookings.departure < '2024-02-26') 
AND 
  people.id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT 
      stays.person_id
    FROM 
        stays
        INNER JOIN bookings ON bookings.id = stays.booking_id 
      WHERE 
        bookings.arrival >= '03-26-2024')
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed to make use of the Stay Database. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```
valid_bookings, invalid_bookings = 
  Booking.partition do |booking|
    booking.departure < one_month_ago && 
    booking.arrival < Time.current
  end
    
Person.where( 
  id: valid_bookings.pluck(:person_id) - 
      invalid_bookings.pluck(:person_id)
)
```

Comment: That will most likely fail due to SQL query size limitations as it will result in an Array of up to 3.8MM integers that will be converted to an `IN()` clause